# Nest.js error with ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './push-service-account.json'

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I tried to find a solution to the problem, I don’t think that the option to remove package-lock.json is suitable for me, since I install dependencies from it using npm ci.
In project i have Node: 12.22.12
npm: 6.14.16
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx9LJ.png)

Comment: Can you share a minimal example to reproduce the error.

Comment: It looks like the file does not exist on the specified directory. If it is in the root, use `process.cwd()` as prefix.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your `PushService` you are trying to read `./push-service-account.json`. This may look fine in your `src` directory, but when you compile, Typescript won't move the `json` file for you. You either need to use a post-build step that moves all `.json` files you plan to read to the relative `dist` location, or you should put all of these `.json` files in a common directory relative to your project root so that you can use `fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), 'common', fileName))`

Comment: i have push.service.js file , who lives in dist/src/common/push
and push.service.ts  who lives in src/common/push 
in both file i have:  const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./push-service-account.json', 'utf-8')); 

Thank you very much for such a quick response, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: The `push.service.js` was created when you compiled the project using the `nest build`, `nest start --watch`, or `tsc` command in your terminal. Typescript took the `ts` code and transpiled it to js into the `outDir` (`dist`). Like I said, `tsc` doesn't move `json` files, at least if they are not a part of `require` or `import` calls